# how to give alert if the app is already installed in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

How to give alert if the app is already installed in android,if not how to provide the link to android market???
I tried here

Here in For loop i need to quit

```
  public void onClick(View v) 
    { 
          final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
           //here i get set of installed apps
         List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

      for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 
       {
            //how do i check for installed package with clicked package

          String data=packageInfo.packageName;

          if(data.equals("com.bb"))
          {
            String TAG ="MyActivity";
            Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
            Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
            Toast.makeText(Listing.this, "You have Installed this Package:com.bb" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

          }

                //if the package is not installed, do this

                  else 
          {


            String dictionary=items[position];
            Toast.makeText(Listing.this, dictionary , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if(dictionary.equalsIgnoreCase("Acronyms"))
            {
                String dictionary2="MAcronyms";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com." + dictionary2));
                startActivity(intent);
             }
                    }
              }   
             }
```

the problem is loop is still running if, if condition fails(for eg..55 times it enters else Block)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     public void onClick(View v) 
      {

     String str = "aaa";

     if(package1(str)==1)
     {
         Toast.makeText(Listing.this, "You have Installed this Package:aaa" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
     else
     {
            String dictionary2="bba";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com." + dictionary2));
            startActivity(intent);
     }

  }

     }

public int package1(String str)
{
      int i=0;

      final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        //get a list of installed apps.
      List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

      for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 
       {

          String data=packageInfo.packageName;
          if(data.equals(str))
          {
            i=1;

           }
                else
                    {
                   //i=0;

                     }

                 }
                 return i;

              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try clean->build, and then the following code-

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{ 
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    //here i get set of installed apps
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 
    {
        //how do i check for installed package with clicked package

        String data=packageInfo.packageName;

        if(data.equals("com.bb"))
        {
            String TAG ="MyActivity";
            Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
            Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
            Toast.makeText(Listing.this, "You have Installed this Package:com.bb" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            break;
        }else{//if the package is not installed, do this


            String dictionary=items[position];
            Toast.makeText(Listing.this, dictionary , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if(dictionary.equalsIgnoreCase("Acronyms"))
            {
                String dictionary2="MAcronyms";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com." + dictionary2));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yeah i did that but, else loop Started to run for 55times dude

Comment: What? Are you sure? Now please clean build. And try the updated answer. Or simply copy paste it.

Comment: Packages will contain 55 pack name...See the for loop it will run for 55 times hence else loop do..

Comment: See, these are java basics. If your condition in "if" is yielding false, it will hit else every time it enters the for loop. And btw, if and else are not loops. You may say them block.

Comment: yes i know that...now how to check and iterate the loop friend

Comment: Ohh. Nice. Please let us all know how.